# TCL can’t use variable substitution inside curly brackets

Tags: variables, tcl

I'm having a problem where variables are being interpreted as a string rather than the intended value.

I'm trying to append pairs of numbers to a list, grouped by curlys, but it doesn't work with variable substitution.

```
set new_list {}
lappend new_list {4 5}
lappend new_list {7 8}
puts "$list"
```

Output:

```
{4 5} {7 8}
```

This is the desired format.
However when I try the following, let's say for instance I wanted all integers to 10 and their squared value to be appended to the list as pairs:

```
for {set i 0} {$i < 10} {incr i} {
    lappend new_list {$i [expr pow($i, 2)]}
}
```

Output:

```
{$i [expr pow($i, 2)]} {$i [expr pow($i, 2)]} {$i [expr pow($i, 2)]} {$i [expr pow($i, 2)]} .... and so on ....
```

I'd want the values as integer pairs: `{1 1} {2 4} {3 9} ...`

Any help in achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to evaluate the words (expressions, etc) at the time that you do the `lappend`. To do that, you build the sublist to be appended with the `list` construction command:

```
for {set i 0} {$i < 10} {incr i} {
    lappend new_list [list $i [expr {$i ** 2}]]
}
```

Braces by themselves mean “do not expand anything in this now”. (That's their *actual* meaning in Tcl. It's just that some commands, such as `for`, then go right ahead and do their thing with what's inside them immediately.) You could, in this case, have put the things to insert in double quotes, but that's bad practice as it can bite you hard once you start using real-world data (such as people's surnames with spaces in); the `list` command is specifically designed (and ***thoroughly tested***) to have no such weaknesses.

In this specific case, I'd write `$i ** 2` instead of `pow($i, 2)` because the latter always produces a floating point result, whereas the former is sensitive to numeric types (just like other `expr` operators).

Comment: Or just use `$i * $i` to square it